# Time-Independent Schrodinger Equation solution formulation (2nd-Order ODE)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Can someone explain the following for me please:

$\bullet$ TISE, insider barrier:

$(\hat T+V)u(x)=Eu(x)$

$-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}=(E-V)u(x)$

Solution: $u(x)=Ae^{-\mathcal{ Hx}}$, $\mathcal {H}=\frac{1}{\hbar} \sqrt{2m(V-E)}$

General solutions to 2nd Order ODE's of the form $y'' - n^2y = 0$ are given by $Ae^{nt} + Be^{-nt}$. Why for this solution have we only considered the negative exponent coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution isn't square-integrable and so it doesn't correspond to a physical state.

Comment: Hello, could you explain a little further please? Both Ae^(nt) and Be^(-nt) are divergent when calculating their square integral over [-infinity, infinity]

Comment: You only have to integrate from 0 to infinity, because for x<0 V=0 and you have to solve the SE for V=0

Comment: Ah thank you very much!